# How to deploy wso2as 5.0.0 and wso2 esb 4.5.1 ..?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to create a proxy in ESB using the wsdl. The log says: "Unable to add proxy service: Failed to add proxy service: HCCProxyService. Check whether the Proxy already exists-Failed to add proxy service: HCCProxyService. Check whether the Proxy already exists" but existing proxy service is not their in application server,
and other issues is that its always redirect logine page after some moment of time both wso2esb and wso2as application server also.
I don't know what to do. What is the configuration for my scenario? Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are adding already existing proxy. Yo can go to ESB_HOME/repository/deployment/server/synapse-config/default/proxy-service folder and check for the your_proxy_name.xml file and delete it. 
Then you may recreate it with the UI. Other issue is due to session timeout. You may ask browser to remember your credentials.

Comment: I tried has here mentioned location but in that place no have any proxy service its proxy-service folder totally empty folder and other issue due to session timeout , location repository/conf/tomcat/carbon/WEB-INF/web.xml, I increased the session time out value but i m also getting same issue.